# How to mock a HttpServletRequest's BufferedReader payload in Grails/Spock

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

I have a Grails controller that expects an XML payload.

I fetch the XML payload like this in a Grails controller.

```
def xmlPayload = request.reader.text
```

That part works fine, but I'm struggling to mock this payload in a unit test.

I've tried both of the following, but the debugger is showing 'request.reader' to be null in both approaches.

Approach #1:

```
void "test controller method"(){
    setup:
    def mockBufferedReader = Mock( BufferedReader )
    mockBufferedReader.getText() >> '<hello/>'
    request.getReader() >> mockBufferedReader
    ....
```

Approach #2:

```
void "test controller method"(){
    setup:
    def mockBufferedReader = Mock( BufferedReader )
    mockBufferedReader.getText() >> '<hello/>'
    request.metaClass.getReader = { -> mockBufferedReader }
    ....
```

'request' in a unit test is a GrailsMockHttpServletRequest, so I presumed I could mock its methods like this (3rd line of both approaches), but so far no luck.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Is the specification inside a spock block (when, then, etc.)?

Comment: No, it's at the start of an individual unit test; i.e., in the implicit 'setup:' block before any when:/then:/etc. blocks. 

I've updated the example to be clearer.

Comment: What exactly `request` is? If it's not a mock, can't you just: a) override the method b) set the `reader` property c) ...  w/o any Groovy magic. If it is a mock, the #1 approach should work

Comment: Could You provide a minimal working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
class EchoController {
    def echo () {
        render (request.reader.text)
    }
}


@TestFor(EchoController)
class EchoSpec extends Specification {
    def "echos XML data" () {
        request.XML = '<hello/>'

        when:
        controller.echo ()

        then:
        response.text == '<hello/>'
    }
}
```

See **Testing XML and JSON Requests** in [Unit Testing Controllers](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingControllers).

Comment: Yep, I was overthinking it. That nailed it! Thanks for the doc ref too.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to provide contents for a request, then you don't need to mock anything.

```
 def "Spock works as expected"() {
    given:
    def request = new GrailsMockHttpServletRequest(content: '<hello/>')

    when:
    def result = request.getReader().getText()

    then:
    result == '<hello/>'
 }
```

One purpose of such *Mock* classes (as in Spring Test etc.) is to avoid explicit mocking with external libraries.